# Obtain an environment variable over the network from another computer

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, environment-variables

I have a myuserid@remotemachine on my network to which I have access via public/private key ssh (ie, doesn't prompt for password, logs me straight in). Is there a way, from Python (or bash, or any other standard linux command) on my local computer, to read one of *myuserid*'s environment variables on *remotemachine* without needing to run a pre-prepared remote script?

Comment: Not unless the script is executed remotely, no, or you execute an SSH call to echo the variable or similar via your script (which requires you to set up passwords, auth, etc.).  Python, etc. have no insight into the active env vars on a remote system unless they're executed *on* the remote system

Comment: +1... *users* don't have environments - *processes* do. So you'd need to execute some kind of remote process (the most obvious one being a remote shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, you can use ssh to run a remote command

try this in your terminal:

```
ssh myuserid@remotemachine echo \$HOSTNAME
```

Comment: it is not a remote script - you send this command via ssh, execute it on remote machine, and pipe the result back. it does not need you to have anything *prepared* on the remote machine.

Comment: @FangQ precisely. That's what I meant. I'll modify my question to ensure this is clearer.

Comment: @FangQ I'm having a problem. The environment variable I want is set in the my remote shell's .bashrc. The answer above simply runs echo without first running bashrc. So how do I "run" bashrc first and then get the environment variable?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne That requires a login shell to actually parse bashrc.  When you call a command directly in your SSH call like this, it just executes it directly and doesn't necessarily execute the call directly after parsing BashRC.  You can *in theory* prepend `bash` to the `echo` call to force it to parse bashrc and then execute

Answer (score 0):

Short of running a remote process such as with this command from your local system or wherever your script runs (suggested by FangQ)...

```
ssh user@remote echo \$ENVVARNAME
```

...to get the output of the env var you've requested (in this case, `ENVVARNAME` in the example which is a bogus placeholder here), you can't.

There is no way to get the entire list of environment variables without executing a process on the remote system.  Therefore, short of running an SSH call into the remote environment to dump the env vars, and then parse that output, you won't be able to get 'remote' variables.

This applies to Python, Bash, and any other script language - either you have to retrieve the data via a remote process call and parse its output, or you have to run your script on the remote system.